# Django: create endpoint for a file

Tags: python, django

I have a mesh.obj file and I would like to create an endpoint for it. For example, the endpoint could be of the form 'path/to/mesh'. How would I do this?

Comment: add the link to urls.py and linked to a function or class inside your views.py and from views.py return the file you want.

Comment: Other solution it's to create a STATIC file path and give the path as wanted.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/ follow this information,

Comment: @EddwinPaz can you please show me how to format the views.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your urls.py:

```
url(r'^test-files/(?P<name>.+)/$', views.test_files, name='test_files'),
```

In your views.py:

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt # (Allows file download with POST requests, can be omitted)
def test_files(request, name):
    if name == "myxml":
        fsock = open("/djangopath/data/static/files/my.xml", "rb")
        return HttpResponse(fsock)
```